# youtube 150 error in Air app

Tags: air, youtube, youtube-api, flash-builder

Hi
  I'm trying to develop an Air app which includes downloading and playing youtube videos
I have a tilelist of thumbnails and a player which plays the selected version
 The event is

```
   protected function videoList_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
```

{ 
  player.cueVideoById(videoList.selectedItem.actualID); 
   }

Some videos play fine both in flashbuilder and the compiled air app but others throw the 150 player error which is apparently  when the video requested does not allow playback in the embedded player. However, if I go to the youtube site, there is no problem obtaining the embedded code and applying it successfully. The videos I have problems with work fine on web sites like http://www.yvoschaap.com/youtube/

Examples of actualID : works xTFNdHqwiQY; fails SRcnnId15BA
The youtube prefix is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=

TIA

Answer (score 3):

You'll receive error 150 when embedding videos that need age verification and for videos that have other restrictions in your country.

If you load the videos in the non-chromeless player, you will see the real error message. You can try that here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html

To get only the search results that you can actually play, search with the following parameters:

1. format=5 (only return embeddable videos)
2. safeSearch=strict
3. restriction=[your IP or country code]

See http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html for more information